# Is there any way to remove an element from iframed website?

Tags: javascript, web

So, I need to add
https://www.rapidtables.com/tools/notepad.html in my website and I need to remove the header of their website.
Is there any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you do `iframedoc = document.getElementById("my_iframe").contentDocument;` you can do everything you can do with `document`. The problem is that if you dont own the page you are embedding, your edit will be blocked by your browser because of cors (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). To bypass this you need to fetch the page with your backend server and pass the file to your javascript.